# Using the word "difference" in the meaning "result of subtraction" taking into account the negative values

Tags: ambiguity, mathematics

The result of subtraction is called "difference". At first glance it might seem that it shouldn't cause an ambiguity over the value denoted by this word; until we stumble upon subtractions that produce negative results.

What do I actually mean? It is clear that:

> 2 − 5 = −3

But when we say "the difference between 2 and 5" don't we mean "3" in the first place irrespective of the order in which we place the numbers in the sentence? What expression should we use to make it clear, regardless of the context, that we imply "−3"?

Comment: "The difference between 2 and 5" is not the same as "2 minus 5". The former describes magnitude, the latter describes magnitude and direction.

Comment: That's what happens when you allow modern radicals to intrude their novelties upon Classical purity, in math no less than language. :) In writing, −3 is unambiguous; in speech, “minus three”. But it's a question for mathematicians, not philologists, to tell us whether the *difference* (as opposed to the *result*) is minus three or absolute three.

Comment: Or "negative three".

Comment: In maths, the difference between two real numbers x and y is **defined** as the absolute value of x-y. x-y is just called x-y (x take / minus y) - there isn't a universally agreed term (though I think 'directed difference' may have been used).

Comment: @StoneyB The phrase "_ and _" is symmetric in its arguments, and adding in a "between" doesn't change this, but subtraction is not symmetric in its arguments. For this reason, in mathematics, we don't use this phrase due to its imprecision (unless we're simultaneously pointing at a scrawl on a blackboard that clarifies, or unless there's some reason we don't care about sign). :) I recommend non-mathematicians do likewise, but when I stumble across the phrase "the difference between _ and _", I usually interpret it as what J.R. and Edwin said.

Comment: @Billy  That's [my] natural-language understanding, too: if you ask me "What's the difference between their bids?" I say "A hundred thousand dollars" without specifying which is lower.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on Mathematics.SE (where basic research may still be expected).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *only* expression that always means "−3", regardless of context, is "−3". Likewise, the only way to make clear that you mean not just "the difference between 2 and 5" but "2 − 5", is by flat out saying "two minus five".

Incidentally, that's what they ask you in school, "How much is two minus five?" And not "What is the difference between two and five?"

Answer (score 0):

Neither [RegDwigнt's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/95144/406212) nor the comments to the question itself provide a citation to any authority for their apparent view that (a) "difference" means the absolute value (i.e., magnitude) of the result of a subtraction, rather than a signed number or (b) that it does not matter whether you say "the difference of A and B" or "the difference of B and A" because, in their view, these are equivalent assertions.

Apparently not!

Wolfram MathWorld's article on "[Subtraction](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Subtraction.html)" states:

> Subtraction is the operation of taking the difference d=x-y of two numbers x and y. Here, x is called the minuend, y is called the subtrahend, and the symbol between the x and y is called the minus sign. The expression "x-y" is read "x minus y."

This asserts that "the difference of x and y" is "x - y" and thus "difference of" does indeed imply a ordered relation between the two entities that follow.

Wolfram's MathWorld is a reputable source on all things mathematical.the

Comment: Having taught maths to Oxbridge entry level, I've only ever come across the definition 'the difference between two real numbers x and y is  |y - x| =  |x - y|', ie the absolute value of the answer to the subtraction involved. However, Wolfram seems a reasonable authority specifying the alternative, that the difference depends on the ordering of the minuend and subtrahend. I've found some dictionaries giving _both_ definitions, and some lacking clariity. Sadly, I'm not aware of maths references with the respectability of OED for definitions of everyday words or CGEL, ACGEL, McCawley for syntax.

Comment: Most maths primer courses I've just looked through arrogate the absolute value of the  answer to the subtraction, but the related thread on [Mathematics.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1598958/how-to-find-the-difference-between-two-numbers) (the proper place for this question) is 'ambiguous: avoid the term'.